# How to run console yiic for create migration on ubuntu?

Tags: php, yii

A very long time working under windows, remember now how it is done only this time on ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change into the protected folder or wherever your yiic is. Type `./yiic <command>`. To create a new migration type `./yiic migrate create <name>`